How to call HttpClient PostAsync or SendAsync with bearer token to get XML with XML argument?
The call with bearer token to get XML with XML argument is done so far with RestSharp
where
XElement Payload = <Access><AppID>35</AppID><UserToken>QrEil9L9S</UserToken></Access> :
 public string PostFromRest(string API_URL, string subURL, string bearerToken, XElement Payload)
 {

  var client = new RestClient(API_URL);
  var request = new RestRequest(subURL, Method.Post);
  request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
  request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
  request.AddHeader("messageType", "REQUEST");
  request.AddHeader("Authorization", bearerToken);
  request.AddHeader("messageId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
  request.AddHeader("timestamp", DateTime.Now.ToString());
  request.AddXmlBody(Payload, ContentType.Xml);
  var response = client.Execute(request);
  return response.Content;
}

I need to do the same with HttpClient.
I was trying:
HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(API_URL);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", bearerToken);
var content1 = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
new KeyValuePair<string, string>[] {
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Cache-Control", "no-cache"),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Type", "application/xml"),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Accept", "application/xml"),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("messageType", "REQUEST"),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("messageId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
new KeyValuePair<string, string>("timestamp", DateTime.Now.ToString())});

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(subURL, content).Result;

But authentication is failed.
I was trying to use HttpRequestMessage:
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, API_URL))
{
  request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
  request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
  request.Headers.Add("messageType", "REQUEST");
  request.Headers.Add("Authorization", bearerToken);
  request.Headers.Add("messageId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
  request.Headers.Add("timestamp", DateTime.Now.ToString());

  request.Content = new StringContent(Payload.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
  HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
}

But authorization is failed too.
How to call HttpClient with bearer token to get XML with XML argument?

RestClient uses HttpClient underneath so this isn't a RestClient vs HttpClient issue. The two calls are completely different - the first passes data in headers, the second tries to post the same data as form fields. The third attempt uses the wrong headers, and even duplicate ones. Content-Type is a content header and is already set in the StringContent. Trying to pass it as a request header as well is a bug.

We can't guess why you get an authentication error either - perhaps you're using an expired token? Is it actually an authentication error, or a 400 complaining the request is bad? To see what's actually going on use Fiddler or another debugging proxy to see the actual raw HTTP request sent to the server and the actual response. The most common request headers are available as properties of HttpRequestMessage.Headers itself, eg Authorization too.

@PanagiotisKanavos, no, token I was creating myself. I think it was using wrong URL in creation of new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, API_URL)). Another thing I was not sure the proper using standard and custom headers.

Another thing I was not sure the proper using standard and custom headers. There is no hard rule to define first the standard ones and then the custom ones otherwise it won't work. It is more convenient to separate them and if you wish you can use the strongly typed properties for the standard ones (rather than populating a dictionary)...

Here is one way to achieve the same with vanilla HttpClient:

Create an HttpClient instance and set its BaseAddress

var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(API_URL) };


Create an HttpRequestMessage and set the relative URL and the verb

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(subURL));


Set the request headers


I suggest to set the standard ones first and then the custom ones

//Standard headers
request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", bearerToken);

//Custom headers
request.Headers.Add("messageType", "REQUEST");
request.Headers.Add("messageId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
request.Headers.Add("timestamp", DateTime.Now.ToString());


Create and set the request body

var content = new StringContent(Payload.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
request.Content = content;


Send the request and process the response

var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


Enjoy :D


It looks like I did the same but it was a typo of API_URL instead of subURL in creation of new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, API_URL)).
